# Removing an entry out of an Attributes map

Tags: java, attributes

I want to remove entrys out of an attribute map. The problem is that the remove method can't match the key I search for:

```
final Attributes attributes = manifest.getMainAttributes();
symbolicName = getAttributeValue(attributes, "Bundle-SymbolicName");
attributes.remove("Bundle-SymbolicName");
```

When i run that code, the entry with the key "Bundle-SymbolicName" (and every other i try to remove) is still in attributes.

In the debugger i can evaluate the following expressions:

- `attributes.getValue("Bundle-Version")` = 0.1.0.qualifier
- `attributes.containsKey("Bundle-Version")` = false
- `attributes.remove("Bundle-Version")` returns null (Returns the previous attribute value, or null if none.)

Is this a problem with typecasting?

Comment: Notice that the keys of `Attributes` are *not* strings. They are of type `Attributes.Name`.

Comment: To add to RealSkeptic’s comment, getValue(String) is a *convenience method:* https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/jar/Attributes.html#getValue(java.lang.String)

Comment: Thanks, that explains it. I couldn't find the specific type of the key.

Answer (score 0):

[RealSkeptic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4125191/realskeptic) did answer my question: The keys of `Attributes` are not strings. I need to use the type `Attributes.Name`